# Extension of metric definition to two sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

The [standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) of a metric, is a function $d: X\times X \to \mathbb{R}$. 
What is a sensible/common extension of a metric/pseudometric to $\tilde d: X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. distance between elements of different sets?

Comment: you need metric to create a topology ? or what where would you use it ?

Comment: Unless $X\subset Y$, this isn't really an extension of $d$. So, assuming $X$ and $Y$ have no points in common, you could take $\tilde d(x,y)\equiv 1$. This would be something like the standard bounded metric, saying that all members of $X$ are "far" from all members of $Y$. The only problem is that you don't get to test conditions like transitivity because you have unrelated sets as factors in Cartesian product (the domain of $\tilde d$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a fun question to play around with. If $f_X:X\to Z$ and $f_Y:Y\to Z$ are functions, then you could define the "metric" $d:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$ by:
$$d(x,y) = d_Z(f_X(x),f_Y(y))$$
for any metric $d_Z:Z\times Z\to\mathbb{R}$. Then, as $d_Z$ is a metric, we have for all $x\in X$ and $y,z\in Z$:

1. $d(x,y) = d_Z(f_X(x),f_Y(y))\geq 0.$
2. Note that $d(x,y)=0$ is equivalent to $d_Z(f_X(x),f_Y(y))=0$ which is equivalent to $f_X(x)=f_Y(y)$.

It's slightly more difficult to create an analogous triangle inequality, since what you want is: $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$, but what is $d(y,z)$? This is a problem since we are giving the $X$ argument a $Y$ value. Maybe you could require:
$$d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(x',z),$$
where $x'\in X$ is any element such that $f_X(x')=f_Y(y)$. Since this needs to hold for all $y\in Y$, you need for all $y\in Y$ the existence of an $x'\in X$ such that $f_X(x')=f_Y(y)$. A similar statement needs to hold for all $x\in X$ as well. This puts a restriction on the types of functions allowed in this idea. Lastly, you need:
$$d(x,y) = d(y,x).$$
Again, we are swapping the arguments here. Just as above, maybe you could say for all $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ there needs to exist elements $(x',y')\in X\times Y$ such that
$$d(x,y) = d(x',y'),$$
where $f_X(x')=f_Y(y)$ and $f_X(x)=f_Y(y')$. So as you can see getting this idea to mimic a metric puts a lot of restrictions on what is allowed. I believe that the usual metric space definition pops out of this with $X=Y$ and the choice of $id_X = f_X=f_Y$. If you find any other constructions, I'd enjoy seeing them!

Comment: If you are looking for generalisations of metrics, you should consider the remarkable paper by Lawvere available at http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/1/tr1abs.html "Metric spaces, generalized logic and closed categories".

Comment: @RonnieBrown Very cool! Thanks for the link, that looks interesting.

Comment: @CC0607 Thanks! Then the metric would be on $Z$, i.e. $Z\times Z \to \mathbb{R}$, right?  Otherwise, from $X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$, it would not be well-defined? Or I am missing something?

Comment: That is awesome @Ronnie Brown. Thanks so much for sharing!

Comment: @user25004 Yes the metric would have to be on $Z$. The idea (in my post at least) is that although there is no obvious or clear way to define a distance between two objects that lie in different spaces, we can transform them into objects that we can compare in another space. In fact, for this to work you don't even really need bijections, as I'll edit above.

Comment: @user25004 Updated the above.

Answer (score 2):

**From a mathematical point of view:**
Note that if $X\neq Y$ you will have trouble to check the conditions $\tilde d(x,x)=0$ and $\tilde d(x,y)=\tilde d(y,x)$...
Of course if $X\subset Y$ or $Y\subset X$ you might consider $\tilde d$ as the restriction of a metric but I'm not sure that it is was you are asking.

**From an intuitive point of view:**
We should keep in mind that a metric defines the distance between two objects, so if they are not living in the same space (which collects objects of the same nature), the distance between them is, IMHO, meaningless.

Comment: To illustrate my intuitive point of view, I propose you to think at what is the distance between "the concept of metric" and "a monkey"?

Comment: My intuitive response is that the  distance between "the concept of metric" and a "monkey", how ever it is defined, is larger than the distance between "the concept of monkey" and a "monkey".

Comment: Thanks!  Yes I see these problems, but I still know a heterogeneous metric is learned, e.g. in machine learning. My question is mainly about how   can we mathematically deal with the definition of metric. What CC0607 suggests is close to the idea of heterogeneous metric learning, however, I am not sure yet  if the metric can be defined on $X \times Y$, in some way, or on $Z \times Z$ only.

Comment: @user25004 well this is the whole point (at least for me). Defining a metric on $Z\times Z$ means that you send the objects of $X$ and $Y$ in a space where they are of the same nature (i.e. you look at which common property of the objects in $X$ and the objects in $Y$ you want to measure the distance) and there of course a metric is meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most obvious definition is that $d(x,y)$ is a restriction of a metric on $X\cup Y$ to $X\times Y$. Let's look what properties of $d(x,y)$  we can derive from that.

In the following I assume for simplicity that $X\cap Y=\emptyset$.

Let's look at the metric axioms, and what follows:

1. $d(x,y)\ge 0$ with equality if and only if $x=y$.

   Since $X$ and $Y$ are assumed disjunct, this reduces simply to $d(x,y)>0$.
2. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$.

   This obviously makes no sense on $X\times Y$ (however it may be used when deriving conditions).
3. $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y)$.

   Clearly, this cannot be used directly either, since both $z\in X$ and $z\in y$ would give an out-of-domain argument to one of the functions on the right hand side.

However, one can derive relations which also make sense for the restricted version. One obvious possibility is to extend the triangle inequality to three terms, and use symmetry to change the order of the middle term:

$$d(x,y) \le d(x,y') + d(x',y') + d(x',y)$$

Now we have an inequality that follows from the metric axioms, but which can also defined on $X\times Y$ directly, where $x,x'\in X$ and $y,y'\in Y$.

We also need to encode the restriction $d(x,x')>0$ for $x\ne x'$. Again, the triangle inequality helps us:
$$d(x,y) + d(x',y) \ge d(x,x') > 0$$
and therefore we must have
$$\inf_{y\in Y} \left(d(x,y) + d(x',y) \right) > 0.$$
Of course the same must be true also for $y,y'$.

So let's tentatively define:

> A two-set metric on the disjunct sets $X$ and $Y$ is a function $d: X\times Y\to \mathbb R$ fulfilling the following axioms:
>
> 1. $d(x,y) > 0$ for all $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.
> 2. $d(x,y) \le d(x,y') + d(x',y') + d(x',y)$ for all $x,x'\in X$ and $y,y'\in Y$.
> 3. $\inf_{y\in Y}\left(d(x,y) + d(x',y)\right) > 0$ for all $x\ne x'\in X$.
> 4. $\inf_{x\in X}\left(d(x,y) + d(x,y')\right) > 0$ for all $y\ne y'\in Y$.

Clearly every function that is a restriction of a metric on $X\cup Y$ fulfils those axioms. However is the reverse also true?

Well, let's try: We define $D:(X\cup Y)\times (X\cup Y)\to \mathbb R$ as follows:

- If $a\in X$ and $b\in Y$, $D(a,b) = d(a,b)$.
- If $a\in Y$ and $b\in X$, $D(a,b) = d(b,a)$.
- If $a\ne b\in X$, $D(a,b) = \inf_{y\in Y} \left(d(a,y)+d(b,y)\right)$.
- If $a\ne b\in Y$, $D(a,b) = \inf_{x\in X} \left(d(x,a)+d(x,b)\right)$.
- If $a=b$, $D(a,b)=0$.

Now let's see if $D$ is a metric.

Clearly $D(a,b) \ge 0$, with equality if and only if $a=b$. Also by definition, $D(a,b)=D(b,a)$. So what remains to prove is the triangle inequality,
$$D(a,b) \le D(a,c) + D(c,b).$$
If $a,b\in X$ and $c\in Y$, or $a,b\in Y$ and $c\in X$, this follows directly from the definition of $D$. If $a\in X$ and $b\in Y$, it follows from the definition together with the tree-term inequality (part 2 of the definition). Remains the case when all three are in the same set. I expect that also to work out, but I'm now too lazy to check.

Comment: Thanks! That is useful @celtschk!